# I have a muttable map which I want to assign values to keys in Scala

Tags: scala, int, tuples, maps

I need to fill the map based on the data types.

```
   // TODO fill this
    var indexToBoard: Seq[(Int, (Int, Int))] => mutable.Map[Int, (Int, Int)] = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, (Int, Int)]
```

How can I fill the map indexToBoard.

Comment: I do not understand, what is the question?
What have you tried?
What is the problem?

Comment: I tried the .updated() which didn't work and I want to fill in the map based on the data types. So for example, I want to map to be filled with map(0 -> (1,2), 1 -> (1,3))

Comment: what does `data types` mean for you? What is the logic behind the fill? What is an example input and a desired output. - The question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but if you're looking for a way to fill a mutable Map with content from a Seq `seqMapElems`, just construct the Map with [mutable.Map.apply](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/mutable/Map$.html#apply[K,V](elems:(K,V)*):C[K,V]):

```
val muMap = mutable.Map(seqMapElems: _*)
```

In case the mutable Map already exists (empty or non-empty), you can add/update with [`++=`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#++=(xs:scala.collection.IterableOnce[A]):Growable.this.type):

```
muMap ++= seqMapElems
```